# R - Writing from one CSV to another CSV - Weird comma interaction

Tags: r, csv, twitter, formatting

I have a collection of tweets from Twitters API using R.
I have these saved in a .CSV file.  One every day.  Some days, I forget to run the script, so I may have something like

file2015-08-24
file2015-08-22

and I want to be more organized.  Since I missed 8-23, the tweets from 8-23 are just stored in file2015-08-24. I want to create a new .CSV, and move any tweets with a "created_at" time of 08-23 to the 08-23 file, and leave the tweets created on 08-24 in the 08-24 file.

Moving the tweets by date works beautifully.  However, when I transfer the tweets to the new file, my CSV file gets ruined.  Some weird comma interactions are happening.

HERE IS AN EXAMPLE!
On July 31, Hillary Clinton made a tweet.  In my .CSV file the "text" column is stored as such

### TEXT

RT @TheBriefing2016: Phasing out Medicare, repealing ACA, and building barriers to voting means only some people get the "right to rise."

h&

Please note, the above is all in ONE CELL.  I know the h& appears on a second line here with a ton of white space between, but in excel in the CSV this is all one cell. 
However, when I rewrite this line to the new CSV file I get....

### TEXT

RT @TheBriefing2016: Phasing out Medicare, repealing ACA, and building barriers to voting means only some people get the \right to rise.\"
THEN MY CSV SKIPS TO THE NEXT ROW AND PUTS THIS IN THE FIRST COLUMN: h&"
Then data continues to fill columns as normal, but they're obviously in the "wrong" column now as we skipped to the next row, and started back from column 1.

If I open the same two files in Notepad++ to examine the CSV...
In Notepad++ the tweet appears with the first few columns being fine, then the "text" column being on TWO different lines. The first line is :
"RT @TheBriefing2016: Phasing out Medicare, repealing ACA, and building barriers to voting means only some people get the ""right to rise.""
Second line of the "text" :
h&",

When I open the file I rewrote to, its also on two lines :
"RT @TheBriefing2016: Phasing out Medicare, repealing ACA, and building barriers to voting means only some people get the \"right to rise.\"
h&",

I'm not sure what's causing this to appear correctly in my original file, and not here.  This isn't the only tweet that does it. A bunch others with quotes in them do as well.  I feel like its breaking somewhere from the quotes.

Here is the code I used to transfer from one file to another.

```
for(curFile in filenames){
## Read in the file
info = read.csv(curFile, header=TRUE, sep=",")

## Updated DF will hold what is in our original file, MINUS the rows that are getting removed.
updatedDF = info
## Get the file date
fileDate = curFile
fileDate = substr(fileDate, 78, 300)
#fileDate=substr(fileDate,85,300)
fileDate = substr(fileDate, 0, 10)

## Get the header from the file
header = names(info)

## Figure out how many rows of data we have
## This is the number of tweets we have in this data file
numTweets = dim(info)[1]

## For every tweet, starting with tweet #1, up to the last tweet (numTweets)
for( x in 1:numTweets) {
    ## Get the tweets date
    ## We want to get this as a VECTOR so we can do character / string manipulations on it
    tweetDateLine = as.vector(info[x, "created_at"])

    ### To get the date from the file, we are going to need to do some editting to the string
    year = substr(tweetDateLine, nchar(tweetDateLine)-3, 300)
    monthDay = substr(tweetDateLine, 5, 10)

    ### Strip the white space from these
    year = gsub(" ", "", year)
    monthDay = gsub(" ", "", monthDay)

    ### Put them together for a cohesive MMMDDYYYY
    tweetDate = paste(monthDay, year, sep="")

    ### Finally convert this to YYYY-MM-DD format like our original date has as extracted from the file name
    tweetDate = as.Date(tweetDate, "%B%d%Y")

    ### Now we can compare
    ### Make a boolean variable. If it is TRUE they are the same
    isTheSame = (fileDate == tweetDate)

    ### If the date of the tweet and the date of the file are the same...
    if(isTheSame){
        ### Skip to the next tweet
        next
    } ## if(isTheSame){

    ### If the date of the tweet and the date of the file are not the same...
    else{
        ### See if a file exists for the date of that tweet. 
        ### First, construct the file name with the path + the date + .csv
        potentialFileName = paste(path, tweetDate, ".csv", sep="")

        ### Next, see if it exists!
        fileExists = file.exists(potentialFileName)

        ### If the file already exists...
        if(fileExists){

            ### Now we need to add the data
            ### To get row "x" of the data...
            entireRow = info[x,]

            ### Now append the row to that file
            cat(sprintf("Writing tweet to file!\n"))
            write.table(rbind(entireRow),file=potentialFileName,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=",",append=TRUE)                

            ### Delete this line from the original file
            updatedDF = updatedDF[updatedDF$created_at != tweetDateLine, ]
        } ##if(fileExists){

        ### If the file does not already exist
        else{


            ### Create the file
            cat(sprintf("Creating file for date : %s \n", tweetDate))
            file.create(potentialFileName)

            ### Add the header line
            cat(sprintf("Inserting header!\n"))
            write.table(rbind(header), file=potentialFileName, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")

            ### Now we need to add the data
            ### To get row "x" of the data...
            entireRow = info[x,]

            ### Now append the row to that file
            cat(sprintf("Writing tweet to file!\n"))
            write.table(rbind(entireRow),file=potentialFileName,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=",",append=TRUE)

            ### Delete this line from the original file
            updatedDF = updatedDF[updatedDF$created_at != tweetDateLine,]
        } ## else{

    } ## else{

}##for( x in 1:numTweets) {

# Now we must take the updatedDF, which contains the original CSV minus the deleted lines
# And write it back to the original file
# Start with replacing the header
cat(sprintf("Inserting header!\n"))
write.table(rbind(header), file=curFile, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")

# Now print the dataframe back
cat(sprintf("Inserting dataframe!\n"))
write.table(updatedDF, file=curFile, row.names=FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep=",", append=TRUE)
```

}##for(curFile in fileNames){

To further aid you all : https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Epc.jpg This is my view in Excel/NPP for the original, followed by after the move of the tweet to the new file.

If it ALSO helps the tweet that's causing this (well, one of them. There are several.) --> Was a ReTweet of this Tweet.  https://twitter.com/TheBriefing2016/status/627212836339453952

Comment: Are your strings quoted? If so, try adding quote="your_quote_character" as an argument to your read.csv()

Comment: Sometimes they have a quote within them, sometimes they don't.

Comment: In .csv files, sometimes the cells themselves have quotes around them specifically to prevent this type of problem. When you open your file in a plain text editor, what does it look like?

Comment: Looks like what I showed above.  There is no text around them.

Example of two tweets listed below.
Tweet 1, as shown in editor) Don't let a wardrobe malfunction ruin your #FirstDay #BackToSchool outfit. http://t.co/nQLGAem9u4 http://t.co/0HNRooALEh

Tweet 2, as shown in editor.
RT @TheBriefing2016: Phasing out Medicare, repealing ACA, and building barriers to voting means only some people get the \right to rise.\" 
h&"